# ¿Cómo centrar y posicionar bien un formulario al momento de tener las dimensiones de un mobile?

Tags: html, formularios, responsive

Estoy con este formulario de registro en el cuál creo que he repetido los mismos errores que en el formulario publicado anteriormente. Al momento de querer testear si el formulario es responsive a medida que disminuyo las dimensiones de la pantalla se queda posicionado arriba como si estuviera cortado por la cabecera. Paso una imágen para comprender mejor mi error.

- Le he asignado en el html margenes fijos los cuales creo que pueden ser el causante de mi inconveniente

¿Cómo hacer qué el formulario sea responsive y no cambie o se corten partes en las pantallas de mobiles?

**Así debería quedar el diseño tratando de qué se respete este mismo en todas las dimensiones**

[image: bien]

**Y este es mi problema. Se corta por ejemplo en las dimensiones del Samsung s9 o s8, no respetando el diseño anterior**
[image: mal]

```css
/* ===== Google Font Import - Poformsins ===== */

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300;400;500;600;700&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

body {
  background: #504157;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  height: 100vh;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
}


/* ------------- SCROLLBAR ------------- */

body::-webkit-scrollbar {
  height: 1.5px;
  width: 6.5px;
  background-color: #000000;
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #e0e0e0;
  border-radius: 2.5px;
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #acacac;
  border-radius: 2.5px;
}


/* ------------- ELIMINAR SUBRAYADO ------------- */

a:link,
a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* ------------- FORMULARIO ------------- */

.container {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 430px;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 11px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 20px;
}

.container .forms {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: max-content;
  width: 200%;
  transition: height 0.2s ease;
}

.container .form {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 30px;
  background-color: #fff;
  transition: margin-left 0.18s ease;
  border-radius: 11px;
}

.container .form .title {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 27px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.form .title::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -9%;
  height: 3px;
  width: 119.7%;
  background-color: #4070f4;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

.form .input-field {
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.input-field input {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 35px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 450;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;
  border-top: 2px solid transparent;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

.input-field input:is(:focus,
 :valid) {
  border-bottom-color: #4070f4;
}

.input-field i {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  color: #999;
  font-size: 23px;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

.input-field input:is(:focus,
 :valid)~i {
  color: #4070f4;
}

.input-field i.icon {
  left: 0;
}

.form .text {
  color: #333;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 450;
}

.form a.text {
  color: #4070f4;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.form a.text:hover {
  color: #145D56;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.form a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.form .button {
  margin-top: 35px;
}

.form .button input {
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-display: center;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background-color: #4070f4;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button input:hover {
  background-color: #145D56;
}

.form .bstr button {
  border-color: #4070f4;
  font-display: center;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background-color: #4070f4;
  padding: 11px;
}

.bstr button:hover {
  background-color: #145D56;
  border-color: #145D56;
}

.form .login-signup {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.form .checkbox-text {
  margin-top: 2%;
  margin-bottom: 10%;
}

.form .btnF {
  border-color: #4070f4;
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-display: center;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-align: center;
  align-content: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background-color: #4070F4;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 11px
}

.form .btnF:hover {
  background-color: #145D56;
  border-color: #145D56;
}

.container .btn2 {
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 500;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background-color: #145D56;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}

.container .btn2 i {
  font-size: 120%;
  color: #fff;
}

.container .btn2:hover {
  background-color: #2a3837;
  border-color: #1e2525;
}

.buttModal {
  border-color: #4070f4;
  background-color: #4070f4;
}

.buttModal:hover {
  background-color: #145D56;
  border-color: #145D56;
}

.buttModal2 {
  border-color: #2c3b49;
  background-color: #2c3b49;
}

.buttModal2:hover {
  border-color: #232d35;
  background-color: #232d35;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <!-- ===== Iconscout CSS ===== -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unicons.iconscout.com/release/v4.0.0/css/line.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.3.0/css/all.min.css">
  <!-- CSS only -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styleALLForm.css">
</head>

<body>


  <div class="container" style="margin-top: 35%;">
    <a href="/">
      <button type="button" class="btn2 btn-primary"><i class="uil uil-estate"></i> Inicio</button>
    </a>
    <div class="forms" style="height: 850px; margin-top: 9%; margin-bottom: 15%;">
      <div class="form login">
        <span class="title">Formulario de registro</span>

        <form action="/formularioRegistro/salvarFormularioRegistro" id="form" method="POST">
          <div class="input-field">
            <input name="Nombre" type="text" placeholder="Ingresa tú nombre" id="nombre" required>
            <i class="uil uil-user"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="input-field">
            <input name="Apellido" type="text" placeholder="Ingresa tú apellido" id="apellido" required>
            <i class="uil uil-user"></i>
          </div>

          <div class="input-field">
            <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Ingresa tú email" id="email" required>
            <i class="uil uil-envelope icon"></i>
          </div>

          <div class="input-field">
            <input name="password" type="password" placeholder="Ingresa tú contraseña" id="contraseña" required>
            <i class="uil uil-lock icon"></i>
          </div>

          <div class="input-field">
            <input name="Celular" type="tel" placeholder="Ingresa tú celular" id="celular" required>
            <i class="uil uil-mobile-android"></i>
          </div>

          <div class="input-field">
            <input name="NumeroCasa" type="tel" placeholder="Ingresa tú número de casa" id="numeroCasa" required>
            <i class="uil uil-house-user"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="input-field">
            <input name="Calle" type="text" placeholder="Ingresa el nombre de tú calle" id="calle" required>
            <i class="uil uil-house-user"></i>
          </div>

          <div class="input-field">
            <input name="Localidad" type="text" placeholder="Ingresa tú localidad" id="localidad" required>
            <i class="uil uil-location-pin-alt"></i>
          </div>

          <div class="login-signup" style="margin-top: 7%;">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#staticBackdrop">
                            <i class="uil uil-exclamation-circle" style="color: red;"></i>
                            Ver condiciones
                            <i class="uil uil-exclamation-circle" style="color: red;"></i></button>
          </div>
          <div class="bstr d-grid col-12 mx-auto" style="margin-top: 5%;">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="btn" disabled>Enviar</button>
          </div>

          <div class="login-signup" style="margin-bottom: -3%;">
            <span class="text">¿Ya eres miembro?
                            <a href="/login" class="text signup-link">Iniciar Sesión</a>
                        </span>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>




  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="staticBackdrop" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="staticBackdropLabel"><i class="uil uil-user"></i> Condiciones de socios
          </h5>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" style="font-size: 96%;">
          <i class="uil uil-angle-right-b" style="color: #145D56;"></i> Con el fin de validar los datos previamente ingresados en el formulario de registro, se deberá presentar la siguiente documentación al momento de ir a retirar un libro.<br><br>
          <i class="uil uil-exclamation-circle" style="color: red;"></i> Esta entrega de documentos se deberá realizar sólo una vez y es obligatoria.<br><br>

          <li>Fotocopia del DNI.</li>
          <li>Fotocopia de un impuesto(para validar datos).</li><br>

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary buttModal2" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary buttModal" data-bs-dismiss="modal" id="btnModal">Aceptar
                        condiciones</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Se cortan porque estás usando porcentajes en las alturas y también para separar los elementos... y al achicar la pantalla, los porcentajes de las separaciones disminuyen y hace que algunos elementos no se adaptan a su contenido... empujando otros elementos de arriba o abajo...

Comment: Ahí los coloqué en automático y mejoro. Ahora ya no lo corta. Pero tengo la mitad del botón del INICIO sobre el borde superior del formulario, Eso como puedo resolverlo sin colocar los margenes que era lo qué estaba utilizando?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tu HTML, tienes márgenes con porcentajes, esto hace que cuando la pantalla sea más pequeña, los márgenes van reduciendo, haciendo que los elementos se muevan y/o se salgan de su contenedor.

Entonces, quitaré todos tus `margin` que están afectando a tu formulario, estos `margin` están en tu HTML, y estás usando los porcentajes (es por eso que al achicar la pantalla, la separación de los elementos también disminuyen... y dan una mala perspectiva y afectarían a los demás elementos):

```
<div class="container"> <!-- aquí quito el style="margin-top: 35%;" -->
  <a href="/">
    <button type="button" class="btn2 btn-primary"><i class="uil uil-estate"></i> Inicio</button>
  </a>
  <!-- aquí quito el margin-top: 9%; margin-bottom: 15%; -->
  <!-- tu altura, me parecía muy grande, así que le puse 600px, esto lo puedes modificar a tu gusto -->
  <div class="forms" style="height: 600px;">
    <div class="form login">
      <!-- todo el contenido de tu formulario -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Ahora, modifiquemos tu formulario. Hagamos que el formulario (llamado `form`) tenga la misma altura de tu contenedor `forms` (que es el div padre, el que encierra tu formulario), y también le indico que tenga scroll vertical con `overflow-y: scroll;`:

```
.container .form {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 30px;
  background-color: #fff;
  transition: margin-left 0.18s ease;
  border-radius: 11px;
  height: 600px; /* misma altura del form padre, que es la clase "forms" */
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

También vi que tu scroll tiene diseño pero solo para el `body`, entonces puse el selector global `*` para que el diseño del scroll esté también en tu formulario (ya que vamos a visualizarlo en pantallas chicas, todo depende a la altura que le pongas):

```
*::-webkit-scrollbar {
  height: 1.5px;
  width: 6.5px;
  background-color: #000000;
}

*::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #e0e0e0;
  border-radius: 2.5px;
}

*::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #acacac;
  border-radius: 2.5px;
}
```

Código completo:

```css
/* ===== Google Font Import - Poformsins ===== */

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300;400;500;600;700&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

body {
  background: #504157;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  height: 100vh;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
}


/* ------------- SCROLLBAR ------------- */

*::-webkit-scrollbar {
  height: 1.5px;
  width: 6.5px;
  background-color: #000000;
}

*::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #e0e0e0;
  border-radius: 2.5px;
}

*::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #acacac;
  border-radius: 2.5px;
}


/* ------------- ELIMINAR SUBRAYADO ------------- */

a:link,
a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* ------------- FORMULARIO ------------- */

.container {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 430px;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 11px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 20px;
}

.container .forms {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: max-content;
  width: 200%;
  transition: height 0.2s ease;
}

.container .form {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 30px;
  background-color: #fff;
  transition: margin-left 0.18s ease;
  border-radius: 11px;
  height: 600px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.container .form .title {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 27px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.form .title::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -9%;
  height: 3px;
  width: 119.7%;
  background-color: #4070f4;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

.form .input-field {
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.input-field input {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 35px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 450;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;
  border-top: 2px solid transparent;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

.input-field input:is(:focus,
 :valid) {
  border-bottom-color: #4070f4;
}

.input-field i {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  color: #999;
  font-size: 23px;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

.input-field input:is(:focus,
 :valid)~i {
  color: #4070f4;
}

.input-field i.icon {
  left: 0;
}

.form .text {
  color: #333;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 450;
}

.form a.text {
  color: #4070f4;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.form a.text:hover {
  color: #145D56;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.form a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.form .button {
  margin-top: 35px;
}

.form .button input {
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-display: center;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background-color: #4070f4;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button input:hover {
  background-color: #145D56;
}

.form .bstr button {
  border-color: #4070f4;
  font-display: center;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background-color: #4070f4;
  padding: 11px;
}

.bstr button:hover {
  background-color: #145D56;
  border-color: #145D56;
}

.form .login-signup {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.form .checkbox-text {
  margin-top: 2%;
  margin-bottom: 10%;
}

.form .btnF {
  border-color: #4070f4;
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-display: center;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-align: center;
  align-content: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background-color: #4070F4;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 11px
}

.form .btnF:hover {
  background-color: #145D56;
  border-color: #145D56;
}

.container .btn2 {
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 500;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background-color: #145D56;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}

.container .btn2 i {
  font-size: 120%;
  color: #fff;
}

.container .btn2:hover {
  background-color: #2a3837;
  border-color: #1e2525;
}

.buttModal {
  border-color: #4070f4;
  background-color: #4070f4;
}

.buttModal:hover {
  background-color: #145D56;
  border-color: #145D56;
}

.buttModal2 {
  border-color: #2c3b49;
  background-color: #2c3b49;
}

.buttModal2:hover {
  border-color: #232d35;
  background-color: #232d35;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- ===== Iconscout CSS ===== -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unicons.iconscout.com/release/v4.0.0/css/line.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.3.0/css/all.min.css">
    <!-- CSS only -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styleALLForm.css">
  </head>

  <body>


    <div class="container">
      <a href="/">
        <button type="button" class="btn2 btn-primary"><i class="uil uil-estate"></i> Inicio</button>
      </a>
      <div class="forms" style="height: 600px;">
        <div class="form login">
          <span class="title">Formulario de registro</span>

          <form action="/formularioRegistro/salvarFormularioRegistro" id="form" method="POST">
            <div class="input-field">
              <input name="Nombre" type="text" placeholder="Ingresa tú nombre" id="nombre" required>
              <i class="uil uil-user"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="input-field">
              <input name="Apellido" type="text" placeholder="Ingresa tú apellido" id="apellido" required>
              <i class="uil uil-user"></i>
            </div>

            <div class="input-field">
              <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Ingresa tú email" id="email" required>
              <i class="uil uil-envelope icon"></i>
            </div>

            <div class="input-field">
              <input name="password" type="password" placeholder="Ingresa tú contraseña" id="contraseña" required>
              <i class="uil uil-lock icon"></i>
            </div>

            <div class="input-field">
              <input name="Celular" type="tel" placeholder="Ingresa tú celular" id="celular" required>
              <i class="uil uil-mobile-android"></i>
            </div>

            <div class="input-field">
              <input name="NumeroCasa" type="tel" placeholder="Ingresa tú número de casa" id="numeroCasa" required>
              <i class="uil uil-house-user"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="input-field">
              <input name="Calle" type="text" placeholder="Ingresa el nombre de tú calle" id="calle" required>
              <i class="uil uil-house-user"></i>
            </div>

            <div class="input-field">
              <input name="Localidad" type="text" placeholder="Ingresa tú localidad" id="localidad" required>
              <i class="uil uil-location-pin-alt"></i>
            </div>

            <div class="login-signup" style="margin-top: 7%;">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#staticBackdrop">
                <i class="uil uil-exclamation-circle" style="color: red;"></i>
                Ver condiciones
                <i class="uil uil-exclamation-circle" style="color: red;"></i></button>
            </div>
            <div class="bstr d-grid col-12 mx-auto" style="margin-top: 5%;">
              <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="btn" disabled>Enviar</button>
            </div>

            <div class="login-signup" style="margin-bottom: -3%;">
              <span class="text">¿Ya eres miembro?
                <a href="/login" class="text signup-link">Iniciar Sesión</a>
              </span>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>




    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="staticBackdrop" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="staticBackdropLabel"><i class="uil uil-user"></i> Condiciones de socios
            </h5>
            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body" style="font-size: 96%;">
            <i class="uil uil-angle-right-b" style="color: #145D56;"></i> Con el fin de validar los datos previamente ingresados en el formulario de registro, se deberá presentar la siguiente documentación al momento de ir a retirar un libro.<br><br>
            <i class="uil uil-exclamation-circle" style="color: red;"></i> Esta entrega de documentos se deberá realizar sólo una vez y es obligatoria.<br><br>

            <li>Fotocopia del DNI.</li>
            <li>Fotocopia de un impuesto(para validar datos).</li><br>

          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary buttModal2" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary buttModal" data-bs-dismiss="modal" id="btnModal">Aceptar
              condiciones</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

Puedes ver mejor los resultados en [**este enlace**](https://codepen.io/christopher-ps/pen/xxaPypR).

Comment: Muy amable, ahí quedo mucho mejor

Answer (score 1):

Tu problema es que `font-size` es muy grande para ese ancho, puedes crear un font-size dinamico usando [clamp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/css/clamp)

```
.input-field input {
    font-size: clamp(0.1em, 3.4vw, 16px);
}
.container .form .title {
    font-size: clamp(0.1em, 6vw, 27px);
}
```

*(tú tienes que jugar con el valor del centro para encontrar el correcto);*

Ejemplo:

```css
/* ===== Google Font Import - Poformsins ===== */

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300;400;500;600;700&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

body {
  background: #504157;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  height: 100vh;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
}


/* ------------- SCROLLBAR ------------- */

body::-webkit-scrollbar {
  height: 1.5px;
  width: 6.5px;
  background-color: #000000;
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #e0e0e0;
  border-radius: 2.5px;
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #acacac;
  border-radius: 2.5px;
}


/* ------------- ELIMINAR SUBRAYADO ------------- */

a:link,
a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* ------------- FORMULARIO ------------- */

.container {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 430px;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 11px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 20px;
}

.container .forms {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: max-content;
  width: 200%;
  transition: height 0.2s ease;
}

.container .form {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 30px;
  background-color: #fff;
  transition: margin-left 0.18s ease;
  border-radius: 11px;
}

.container .form .title {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 27px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.form .title::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -9%;
  height: 3px;
  width: 119.7%;
  background-color: #4070f4;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

.form .input-field {
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.input-field input {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 35px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 450;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;
  border-top: 2px solid transparent;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

.input-field input:is(:focus,
 :valid) {
  border-bottom-color: #4070f4;
}

.input-field i {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  color: #999;
  font-size: 23px;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

.input-field input:is(:focus,
 :valid)~i {
  color: #4070f4;
}

.input-field i.icon {
  left: 0;
}

.form .text {
  color: #333;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 450;
}

.form a.text {
  color: #4070f4;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.form a.text:hover {
  color: #145D56;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.form a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.form .button {
  margin-top: 35px;
}

.form .button input {
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-display: center;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background-color: #4070f4;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button input:hover {
  background-color: #145D56;
}

.form .bstr button {
  border-color: #4070f4;
  font-display: center;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background-color: #4070f4;
  padding: 11px;
}

.bstr button:hover {
  background-color: #145D56;
  border-color: #145D56;
}

.form .login-signup {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.form .checkbox-text {
  margin-top: 2%;
  margin-bottom: 10%;
}

.form .btnF {
  border-color: #4070f4;
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-display: center;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-align: center;
  align-content: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background-color: #4070F4;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 11px
}

.form .btnF:hover {
  background-color: #145D56;
  border-color: #145D56;
}

.container .btn2 {
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 500;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background-color: #145D56;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}

.container .btn2 i {
  font-size: 120%;
  color: #fff;
}

.container .btn2:hover {
  background-color: #2a3837;
  border-color: #1e2525;
}

.buttModal {
  border-color: #4070f4;
  background-color: #4070f4;
}

.buttModal:hover {
  background-color: #145D56;
  border-color: #145D56;
}

.buttModal2 {
  border-color: #2c3b49;
  background-color: #2c3b49;
}

.buttModal2:hover {
  border-color: #232d35;
  background-color: #232d35;
}

.input-field input {
    font-size: clamp(0.1em, 3.4vw, 16px);
}
.container .form .title {
    font-size: clamp(0.1em, 6vw, 27px);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <!-- ===== Iconscout CSS ===== -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unicons.iconscout.com/release/v4.0.0/css/line.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.3.0/css/all.min.css">
  <!-- CSS only -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styleALLForm.css">
</head>

<body>


  <div class="container" style="margin-top: 35%;">
    <a href="/">
      <button type="button" class="btn2 btn-primary"><i class="uil uil-estate"></i> Inicio</button>
    </a>
    <div class="forms" style="height: 850px; margin-top: 9%; margin-bottom: 15%;">
      <div class="form login">
        <span class="title">Formulario de registro</span>

        <form action="/formularioRegistro/salvarFormularioRegistro" id="form" method="POST">
          <div class="input-field">
            <input name="Nombre" type="text" placeholder="Ingresa tú nombre" id="nombre" required>
            <i class="uil uil-user"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="input-field">
            <input name="Apellido" type="text" placeholder="Ingresa tú apellido" id="apellido" required>
            <i class="uil uil-user"></i>
          </div>

          <div class="input-field">
            <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Ingresa tú email" id="email" required>
            <i class="uil uil-envelope icon"></i>
          </div>

          <div class="input-field">
            <input name="password" type="password" placeholder="Ingresa tú contraseña" id="contraseña" required>
            <i class="uil uil-lock icon"></i>
          </div>

          <div class="input-field">
            <input name="Celular" type="tel" placeholder="Ingresa tú celular" id="celular" required>
            <i class="uil uil-mobile-android"></i>
          </div>

          <div class="input-field">
            <input name="NumeroCasa" type="tel" placeholder="Ingresa tú número de casa" id="numeroCasa" required>
            <i class="uil uil-house-user"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="input-field">
            <input name="Calle" type="text" placeholder="Ingresa el nombre de tú calle" id="calle" required>
            <i class="uil uil-house-user"></i>
          </div>

          <div class="input-field">
            <input name="Localidad" type="text" placeholder="Ingresa tú localidad" id="localidad" required>
            <i class="uil uil-location-pin-alt"></i>
          </div>

          <div class="login-signup" style="margin-top: 7%;">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#staticBackdrop">
                            <i class="uil uil-exclamation-circle" style="color: red;"></i>
                            Ver condiciones
                            <i class="uil uil-exclamation-circle" style="color: red;"></i></button>
          </div>
          <div class="bstr d-grid col-12 mx-auto" style="margin-top: 5%;">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="btn" disabled>Enviar</button>
          </div>

          <div class="login-signup" style="margin-bottom: -3%;">
            <span class="text">¿Ya eres miembro?
                            <a href="/login" class="text signup-link">Iniciar Sesión</a>
                        </span>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>




  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="staticBackdrop" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="staticBackdropLabel"><i class="uil uil-user"></i> Condiciones de socios
          </h5>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" style="font-size: 96%;">
          <i class="uil uil-angle-right-b" style="color: #145D56;"></i> Con el fin de validar los datos previamente ingresados en el formulario de registro, se deberá presentar la siguiente documentación al momento de ir a retirar un libro.<br><br>
          <i class="uil uil-exclamation-circle" style="color: red;"></i> Esta entrega de documentos se deberá realizar sólo una vez y es obligatoria.<br><br>

          <li>Fotocopia del DNI.</li>
          <li>Fotocopia de un impuesto(para validar datos).</li><br>

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary buttModal2" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary buttModal" data-bs-dismiss="modal" id="btnModal">Aceptar
                        condiciones</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```